# to display selected contact from phone book to edit text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

What is have done so far is on press of a button "Add contact" phone book gets open and then select a contact that get displayed in Edittext View and when another button "Add More Contacts" is pressed, a another Edit-Text View gets displayed on the top for which i can again select the contact from phone book.
But the problem that i am facing is when i select contact for second Edit-Text View it replace the contact of the previous edit text. What to do in this case.
Code that is used for displaying edit-text Views

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Button btn_cntct;
public int REQUESTCODE = 1;
private LinearLayout layoutLinear;
private Button btn_addmore_cntct;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // defining button elements for picking contacts from phone-book
    btn_cntct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bpickperson);
    btn_cntct.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // using Intent for fetching contacts from phone-book
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUESTCODE);
        }

    });

    layoutLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mLayout);
    btn_addmore_cntct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.baddmorecontacts);
    btn_addmore_cntct.setOnClickListener(OnClick());
    EditText editview = new EditText(this);
    editview.setText("Add more");
}


private OnClickListener OnClick() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // changing return type "null" to "new OnClickListner"
    return new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            EditText tab = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
            tab.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            // adding (0) to display edit-text view on the top
            layoutLinear.addView(tab, 0);
            tab.requestFocus();

        }
    };

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        Log.i("data", uri.toString());
        if (uri != null) {
            Cursor c = null;
            try {
                c = getContentResolver()
                        .query(uri,
                                new String[] {
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
                                null, null, null);

                if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String name = c.getString(0);
                    String number = c.getString(1);
                    int type = c.getInt(2);

                    showSelectedNumber(name, number, type);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    c.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


public void showSelectedNumber(String name, String number, int type) {
    EditText userNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    String typeNumber = (String) ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone
            .getTypeLabel(getResources(), type, "");
    userNumber.setText(name + ": " + number + " " + typeNumber);

}
```

and my logcat is

```
01-21 14:29:01.766: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(590): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-21 14:29:04.327: I/data(590): content://com.android.contacts/data/1
01-21 14:29:04.387: I/layoutLinear is not  null(590): not null
01-21 14:29:04.387: I/edittext is null(590): null
01-21 14:29:04.437: D/AndroidRuntime(590): Shutting down VM
01-21 14:29:04.437: W/dalvikvm(590): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-21 14:29:04.477: E/AndroidRuntime(590): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 14:29:04.477: E/AndroidRuntime(590): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/1 flg=0x1 (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.zzz1/com.example.zzz1.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-21 14:29:04.477: E/AndroidRuntime(590):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
01-21 14:29:04.477: E/AndroidRuntime(590):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2574)
01-21 14:29:04.477: E/AndroidRuntime(590):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-21 14:29:04.477: E/AndroidRuntime(590):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:961)
01-21 14:29:04.477: E/AndroidRuntime(590):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-21 14:29:04.477: E/AndroidRuntime(590):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-21 14:29:04.477: E/AndroidRuntime(590):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-21 14:29:04.477: E/AndroidRuntime(590):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 14:29:04.477: E/AndroidRuntime(590):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-21 14:29:04.477: E/AndroidRuntime(590):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-21 14:29:04.477: E/AndroidRuntime(590):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-21 14:29:04.477: E/AndroidRuntime(590):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-21 14:29:04.477: E/AndroidRuntime(590): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-21 14:29:04.477: E/AndroidRuntime(590):  at com.example.zzz1.MainActivity.showSelectedNumber(MainActivity.java:145)
01-21 14:29:04.477: E/AndroidRuntime(590):  at com.example.zzz1.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:115)
01-21 14:29:04.477: E/AndroidRuntime(590):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
01-21 14:29:04.477: E/AndroidRuntime(590):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2528)
01-21 14:29:04.477: E/AndroidRuntime(590):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: How you are setting Text ? Post your entire code.

Comment: sorry ?? i didn't get you

Comment: @bhanukaushik: where are you setting the text?

Comment: @bhanukaushik tab.setText() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you should do is that you have to give an ID to your created EditText , everytime you create a new EditText , like the following :

```
private int id = 1 ; 

private OnClickListener OnClick() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // changing return type "null" to "new OnClickListner"
    return new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            EditText tab = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
            tab.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        // here you set the ID 
        tab.setId(id);
        // and increment it 
        id++;
            // adding (0) to display edit-text view on the top
            layoutLinear.addView(tab,0);
            tab.requestFocus();

        }
    };

}
```

then in the showSelectedNumber method , you should get the EditText from the LinearLayout and get it by the id that you assigned to you recently created EditText , like the following :

```
public void showSelectedNumber(String name, String number, int type) {

    if(layoutLinear== null ) {
        Log.i("layoutLinear is null" , "null");
    }else {
        Log.i("layoutLinear is not  null" , "not null");

    }

    EditText userNumber = (EditText) layoutLinear.getChildAt(0);
    if(userNumber == null ) {
        Log.i("edittext is null" , "null");
    }else {
        Log.i("edittext is not  null" , "not null");

    }
    String typeNumber = (String) ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone
            .getTypeLabel(getResources(), type, "");
    userNumber.setText(name + ": " + number + " " + typeNumber);

}
```

Hope That Helps .

Comment: Sorry the application has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again

Comment: please have a look on the logcat

Comment: this is the code at line 132:. userNumber.setText(name + ": " + number + " " + typeNumber);

Comment: i just updated the code , please tell me what you get in the logcat

Comment: same "application stopped unexpectedly"

Comment: i know , but i wrote somthing to the log , to know if the editText is null or not , i want that log .
please check my updated code to see what i am telling about the log

Comment: please check now , and keep updating the log

Comment: please update the log , i am here until this is working

Comment: Yipeee .....Really thank you .. for your help and support and giving your precious time over the code... u cracked it finally :)

Answer (score 0):

In `showSelectedNumber` method, `EditText userNumber` will always be the first `EditText`, because you try to find it by `R.id.edittext`. That's why the first `EditText`'s content will be changed.

You should assign a new `id` for new-added `EditText`, in `OnClickListener`.

```
EditText tab = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
// For example
tab.setId( A_NEW_ID );
```

Then, in `showSelectedNumber`,

```
EditText userNumber = (EditText) findViewById( A_NEW_ID );
```

==================================================

Or, you can just holder new-added `EditText` in a list. Then use the last one each time you add a new contact.

Answer (score 0):

store reference in class variable when you click on EditText and then pass this EditText to method when you setText().

```
public void showSelectedNumber(String name, String number, int type,EditText et) {
EditText userNumber = et;
String typeNumber = (String) ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone
        .getTypeLabel(getResources(), type, "");
userNumber.setText(name + ": " + number + " " + typeNumber);

}
```